# How To Download Test Script As Attachment in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I use selenium and TestNG jar files on eclipse java. After a writing and compiling a test script, Is there an embedded feature in eclipse to download the test script instead of copying and pasting it in an editor like notepad? If no, is notepad the best editor out there for keeping a script in its original format? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done with eclipse. Once I needed it too to register the copyright of my apps, and I had to do it manually in notepad.You can also useeditplus. So, good luck :)